# react router useparams comes back as undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom V5.  A simple version of my code is:
Index.tsx:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router basename={urlExtra}>
        <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.tsx

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <main css={content}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact={true} path={"/"} component={Home} />
          {Routes.map((routes: any) => (
            <Route path={routes.path} key={routes.path} component={routes.component} />
          ))}
          <Route path="*" component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Navbar.tsx:

```
const NavBar: React.FC = () => {
  const { organizationId, tenantId } = useParams();
....
```

since my Navbar is outside of my routing pages, it never gets updated and all of the parameters stay as 'undefined' when i switch pages.  How can i tell the navbar links to update when a page change updates one of those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useParams` can only extract the params from routes it is contained within. It's essentially a short-cut for the `useRouteMatch` hook, using the combined route data for a certain depth in the component tree.

You can manually test for certain routes by creating your own instance of the route matching hook at any depth. For example:

```
const NavBar: React.FC = () => {
  const match = useRouteMatch({
    path: "/buildings/:organizationId/:tenantId",
    exact: true
  });
}
```

The value of `match` will be `null` when the route does not match, and when it does match, it returns an object which has a property that will look like this:

```
params: {
  organizationId: "someOrganzationId",
  tenantId: "someTenantId"
}
```

For more information, look at the documentation for [useRouteMatch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) and the function [matchPath](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/matchPath) which it is built on top of.

**Edit:**

You can use more complex paths (including regexes) to match a variety of route syntaxes. In this example, the paths `Test1` and `Test2` will match, but not `Test3` or `Tests`:

```
function NavBar(){  
  const match = useRouteMatch('/Test:i([1-2])/:id1/:id2');
  
  const { id1, id2 } = {
    id1: match?.params.id1,
    id2: match?.params.id2
  };
  
  return match && (
    <ul>
      <li><Link to={`/Test1/${id1}/${id2}`}>Test 1</Link>
      </li>
      <li><Link to={`/Test2/${id1}/${id2}`}>Test 2</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: honestly i'm not sure how to use this feature with the example i'm talking about.  basically my navbar is outside of the pages that get loaded, so that every time a different page loads, the navbar doesn't update, and i don't know how to push to the navbar 'hey, parameters have changed, so the links in the navbar should change/update along with it'

Comment: Pull the parameters out of the `match` object and plug them straight into your JSX, or put `match` in the dependency array of a `useEffect`/`useMemo` and get some derived presentation data out of it. With `useRouteMatch` in place, your `NavBar` should now rerender on new matching/unmatching routes or new params. If this can't be done then you might need to show the rest of the component implementation.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but here is my silly example: https://codepen.io/vishnu4/pen/LYWpazQ .  click on a button, which pushes an ID value to a Route.  the navbar doesn't refresh with these ID values.  I can try to use useRouteMatch, but that doesn't seem to update correctly for me.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand exactly what you're going for but here is a fork which seems to do what you expect: https://codepen.io/lazaruswist/pen/NWpGVXL?editors=0011. These links are naturally going to be dead until you are already on a route which fills out the params.

Comment: nah, you got it.  I made a few minor edits for my case, but you gave me what i was missing.  Thank you!